# If the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is all sets of the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ what is product topology on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Probably the answer to this question is too obvious for it to be asked but I want to make sure my assumption is correct.
Consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology that has basis consisting of all open intervals of the form $(a,b)$ with $a<b$. The product topology on the the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a basis consisting of all sets of the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ with $a<b$ and $c<d$. With this in mind, I will assume that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}...$ is given by sets of the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)\times (e,f)\times...$ with $n$ factors of the type $(i,j)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right, though we often write$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}(a_j,b_j)=(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n)$$to avoid running out of letters.

Comment: Great, thank you.